# finding server uptime from another server using powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to find the server up time of other servers using powershell command from one server. I am using below command to query the other server but could not get the required result.

```
$lastboottime = (Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $server -Credential $altcreds -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).LastBootUpTime
Write-Host $lastboottime
```

Can someone share the best way to find the other servers uptime. Is there any way in sqlserver or sqlserver stored procedure

Comment: please add some hint about what the problem is. [*grin*] that code SHOULD work ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it to a valid Datetime object, use the `ConvertToDateTime` method...

```
$WMI = (Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $server -Credential $altcreds -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
[datetime]::Now - ($WMI.ConvertToDateTime($WMI.LastBootUpTime))
```

If you just need the date:

```
$WMI.ConvertToDateTime($WMI.LastBootUpTime)
```

Comment: I am doing this in my next line.

Comment: so what exactly you mean by not the required results?

Comment: However, the error is in $server and $altcreds. can you tell the right way of assigning server name and credentials to a variable.

Comment: `$altcreds = get-credential` for manual setup or `$altcreds = New-Object pscredential("username",(ConvertTo-SecureString "Password" -AsPlainText -Force))` for the server is just a simple string `$server = "servername"`